# Attempts to Zip files by date not working as expected

Tags: command-line, unix, zip

I am trying to zip up a bunch of files, but only those created on a certain date.  I'm trying to use the -t option, but it's not finding the files that I can clearly see are there.

This is a sample of what's in my directory when I do an ls -lrt:

```
Oct  6 21:59 file07061259
Oct  6 23:54 file07062354
Oct  7 06:14 file07070614
Oct  7 06:54 file07070654
Oct  7 07:12 file07070712
Oct  7 07:26 file07070726
```

I want to zip up only files from October 7th.  So I tried this:

```
zip -t10072022 10-07-22_logs.zip
```

but it gave this result:

```
zip error: Nothing to do! (10-07-22_logs.zip)
```

I also tried adding the current directory to the command:

```
zip -t10072022 10-07-22_logs.zip .
zip error: Nothing to do! (10-07-22_logs.zip)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess you need to tell `zip` the files you want to zip (and *then* some of them may be filtered out because of `-t`), or tell it to work *recursively* on `.`. Not tested, therefore not an answer.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I tried adding -r option, and that sort of worked?  I got results now!  But if I run it for a different date (not today's date), the result has the date I want PLUS ALL FUTURE DATES.  Is there any way to get files JUST from the date I list?

Comment: `man 1 zip`: `-t` *and* `-tt`.

Comment: You're asking for files on July 10, not October 7. Use DDMMYYYY format.

Comment: @Paul `zip` *does* expect `mmddyyyy`. In my opinion this format is as twisted as `MM:SS:HH` would be for time, so I would use `yyyy-mm-dd` (ISO 8601) which is fortunately also supported. Guess if I'm from the US. :) Anyway I believe your comment is wrong.

Comment: As @KamilMaciorowski said, you need both `-t` (`--from-date`) and `-tt` (`before-date`), and the format of both is "mmddyyyy". There is no one parameter that does it.

Comment: How do I do both -t and -tt at the same time? `zip -tttr10072022 10-07-22_logs.zip .` produces an error.

Comment: Most likely `zip -t… -tt… -r …`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski you are correct, my mistake